# Single slit thought experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

If it were possible to fire a single Electron through a slit of exactly the same size, would there be zero interference at the detector?

Answer (score 0):

Think of what even the same size would mean. To make a hole or even a slit, you need the material at that position to be "cut" out. An electron is a subatomic particle and has enough "space" to move through the "solid" metal too. So with this intuition, you can say that well, you really can't make anything the size of an electron rather than the electron itself. An electron can literally travel through solids - with no holes. 
In short, a slit of that dimension will not be practical to make or even exist and even if there were a single slit, what would it interfere with? A single beam can't interfere with itself, and as a general rule, you need atleast two waveforms to have an interference pattern.

Comment: Though it is right that (in a sense) to produce an interference pattern , one needs 2 slits. But it is not true that one needs two waves. There is a single photon interference experiment . A single photon is fired at the slit (obviously the intensity of light is reduced to such an extent ) and the pattern is allowed to build up for some time and one finds the interference pattern again. A single photon interfering with itself. Though I do not know whether the same has been carried out for on electron or not but I am sure about the single photon interference .

Comment: Single slits have diffraction patterns. Electron microscopes (TEMs) generally have a single electron in the sample at a time.

Comment: It was done in an experiment by Merli, Missiroli, and  Pozzi in 1974 with a electron bi-prism which basically works for all practical purposes as a double slit. Repeated later by Tonomura in 1989. Interference is seen even with single hits.

Comment: Right, so what exactly should I edit in my answer? A single electron shows diffraction but interference needs two "sources" - slits in this case. Will this be okay?

Comment: Well a single beam can be made to interfere with itself if made to split or if it forced to pass through a narrow opening (though indeed experimentally difficult hence in the experiments I mentioned they use a somewhat different method). The points is that Huygens principle (spherical waves from every point that interfere etc) works for electron waves the same as in optics. This is e.g.  how  TEM works as Jon Custer also pointed out. Secondly, this interference effect won't go away if you reduce the intensity to single hits.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear as an electron as far as is known is a point particle. Still it seems that you are asking about the diffraction in the limit of vanishing slit width. If the slit width is smaller than the wavelength, the optical path difference as function of angle of transmission becomes too small to cause destructive interference. In the limit the transmitted intensity becomes independent of the angle. Note that the total transmitted intensity also goes to zero.

The above is what a simplified model of the slit system will give. In physical embodiments all kinds of physical effects will play a role such a surface excitations and polarization. Nevertheless the conclusion stands that interference disappears in the limit of a narrow slit.

On the other hand your question may be: what happens if I use a bundle that covers only one slit. In such a case there is no two slit interference,  only single slit diffraction.